# Using axlsx partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I am using `axlxs` and `axlsx_rails`.  I can create inline spreadsheets no problem - for example I have an `index.xlsx.axlsx` file etc.

The problem is I have another action the uses the exact same code so I tried creating a partial `_export.xlsx.axlsx` and moving my code in there.  I then replaced `index.xlsx.axlsx` with `render 'export'`.

I get an excel spreadsheet generated by Excel says it's corrupted.  I can just duplicate my code in another file but there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: There's probably a dry way to do this, but you'll need to provide more information on your environment setup (actions, controllers, and views).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
render partial: 'export', locals: {wb: wb}
```

If you have a different variable than `wb`, pass that in, or pass in `xlsx_package`, etc.

Comment: I see where you are heading with this. I will try it out once I get back to my code.